# IE can't load img to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

[open chorme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsACS.png)

This code is not load image to IE but open in chrome and other web browsers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>VANKOW ERP.</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>#1</h1>        
        <img src="//api.vankow.com/file/images/image047.png" alt="VANKOW">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error in the console?

Comment: HTML1503: 예기치 않은 시작 태그입니다.

Comment: DOM7011:  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Comment: Translation: *"HTML1503: Unexpected start tag."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the `meta` tag in the `head` tag. I think this could also break in IE.

such as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>VANKOW ERP.</title>
</head>
...
```

and add a `http:` or `https:` at beginning of the url:

```
<img src="http://api.vankow.com/file/images/image047.png" alt="VANKOW" />
```

IE does not append this automatically as in modern browsers as Chrome.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't closed your `<h1>` tag properly.

```
<h1>#1/h1>
```

Should be

```
<h1>#1</h1>
```

This most likely is causing IE to parse the trailing image tag incorrectly which would make sense since you're getting `HTML1503: Unexpected start tag` errors.

Comment: Are you sure you've edited it correctly? The `unexpected start tag` error means there is a start tag in your html that's invalid.